# How to use LGSideMenuController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use [LGSideMenuController](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController) in my project.

I have a trouble from step :

```
 // Initialization
- (instancetype)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController;
```

My Question : Where to add it? I have added it in `viewcontroller.h`, is it correct?

and second step is:

```
- (void)setLeftViewEnabledWithWidth:(CGFloat)width
                  presentationStyle:(LGSideMenuPresentationStyle)presentationStyle
               alwaysVisibleOptions:(LGSideMenuAlwaysVisibleOptions)alwaysVisibleOptions; 
- (void)setRightViewEnabledWithWidth:(CGFloat)width
                   presentationStyle:(LGSideMenuPresentationStyle)presentationStyle
                alwaysVisibleOptions:(LGSideMenuAlwaysVisibleOptions)alwaysVisibleOptions;
```

My Question : I have added it in my `viewcontroller.h` . Is it correct?

and third step is:

```
ViewController *viewController = [ViewController new];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

LGSideMenuController *sideMenuController = [[LGSideMenuController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navigationController];

[sideMenuController setLeftViewEnabledWithWidth:250.f
                              presentationStyle:LGSideMenuPresentationStyleScaleFromBig
                           alwaysVisibleOptions:0];

TableViewController *leftViewController = [TableViewController new];

[sideMenuController.leftView addSubview:leftViewController.tableView];
```

My Question - I have added it in my `viewcontroller.m`, but it shows following alert:

```
 not found method setlef... ; setright... and instancetype ;
```

Please help me to integrate it in my projects.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the people who have created that third party lib have made this abundantly clear.

Answer to your questions; Nopes, You don't have to add any of the methods to your ViewController.h file or anywhere else. Methods are already there in `LGSideMenuController.h`. Just import it to the place where you intend to use it.

Assuming that you have downloaded the third party lib and added it to your project, this is what you have to do:

First of all add following line to your `ViewController.h` or `AppDelegate.h` file (If you are [resetting the root VC programmatically](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=set%20root%20view%20controller%20navigation%20controller%20programmatically&rct=j)). Write it where you have rest of your import statements (That means the top of the file).

```
#import "LGSideMenuController.h"
```

Now you can access, create and modify instances of LGSideMenuController in your ViewController.

Then you have to initialize your Side Menu.

The method for that is:

```
- (instancetype) initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController;
```

You can create this like in your `didFinishLaunching` method in your AppDelegate.m :

```
ViewController *viewController = [ViewController new]; //Your root VC
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController]; //Create a new navigation controller and assign your VC to that navigation controller
LGSideMenuController *sideMenuController = [[LGSideMenuController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navigationController]; //Create instance of your side menu and pass your navigation controller as parameter here.
```

Now that you have created an instance, it's time to assign it a left view or right view as you prefer. Right now, let's do left view:

```
[sideMenuController setLeftViewEnabledWithWidth:250.f                        presentationStyle:LGSideMenuPresentationStyleScaleFromBig
                           alwaysVisibleOptions:0];

TableViewController *leftViewController = [TableViewController new];

[sideMenuController.leftView addSubview:leftViewController.tableView];
```

Now just present your sideMenuController, hook the events to right buttons and that's it. If you don't know how to do that either, look up on other Questions on stackoverflow.

However, IDK your requirements but I'd suggest using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) for side menu. It is simple, elegant and really easy to use with plenty of help.

Comment: Thank you very much Bro ! But I have a trouble, I just read one by one code  line and try understand it's mean. kaka I'm stupid !

Comment: LGSideMenuController is just fine. You can even do the whole menu stuff in Storyboard without touching a code and you get a working menu slider when Run it.